# sudoers with php-fpm shell_exec stopped working in 18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I have a bunch of servers with the same configuration and all works flawlessly, so I applied the same on a brand new recently installed with 18.04 but now when:

```
$iptables = shell_exec('sudo /sbin/iptables -t raw -L --line-numbers 2>&1');
var_dump($iptables);
exit;
```

I got:

```
string(54) "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I used to have /etc/sudoers with this exact command. But now, for testing I have:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
Defaults:www-data !requiretty
```

Still the same output :/ . This only fail in php-fpm via nginx.

If I use "php -a" or launch this command via cli, it works ok so I think the system/sudoers configuration is ok, but still I cant figure whats differet in php-fpm.

```
www-data@ns368791:/root$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $iptables = shell_exec('sudo /sbin/iptables -t raw -L --line-numbers 2>&1');
php > var_dump($iptables);
string(197) "Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT) ....
```

My setup is:

```
php --version
PHP 7.2.22-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Sep  2 2019 12:54:33) ( NTS )

root@ns368791:~# uname -a
Linux ns368791 4.15.0-64-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 13:16:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@ns368791:~# nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
```

Thanks